# Webview is not displaying properly in android in version 4.0

Tags: android, android-widget

In my application i am using webview,in web view i am displaying text it is occupying its parent in version less than 4.0 but in version 4.0 it is not filling its parent.I gave width for webview fill parent but i am able to solve this please help me how to solve this issue.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </WebView>
```

and data as

```
  String data = "<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\"\"content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=0,maximum-scale=0,user-scalable=no,target-densitydpi=device-dpi\" /></head>";
        data = data + "<body><center><img width=\"" + width + "\" src=\""
                + topImage + "\" /></center></body></html>";
```

Comment: Your WebView does fill in the parent, tested. Maybe something wrong with content? I see the image width is somewhat custom, do you expect this image to fill in the whole screen? If so, is the width value correct?

Comment: it is filling parent in less than 4.0 but not in 4.0 but text occupying less space when compared with image if problem in content then it should not come in lower versions but is occupying full space there

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
i gave this then it is dispalying full in android 4.0 also